# How to get/parse data from Backbone.LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, local-storage, marionette

I am trying to understand how `Backbone.LocalStorage` is used the from the following [jagin/todos](https://github.com/jagin/todos).

Referring to the [Backbone.Marionette doc](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md), In order to render the list of todos, it should be enough to make the following code:

```
new CompositeView({
  model: someModel,
  collection: someCollection,
  itemView: RowView
});
```

So, referring to the [jagin/todos](https://github.com/jagin/todos) the collection should be an object fetched from the `backbone.localstorage`.

My question is:
I would like to get this `collection/models` from the javascript console.
I did try the following but it returns an object which is different from a backbone.collection.

```
new Backbone.LocalStorage("todos-marionette"); 
// {"name":"todos-marionette","records":["1244f588-be3d-c493-5c86-b2abb997af82"]}
```

Any ideas?